# ASP.net Custom Control, drop down values must be populated server side, selected values lost on post back?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback, selectedvalue

Hi there I guess I am in need of some clarification after getting quite confused looking at different examples.

I am in the middle of creating a custom date control with 3 drop down boxes, a bit like you see on the login page of Facebook.

I have the control working fine in terms of its client side functionality, the problem came when trying to retrieve the values server side.

It would seem that as I am populating the drop downs via JavaScript, when I go sever side it is completely unaware of the selected value.

After reading around I decided to move the child controls to the OnInit function, with in this I make a call to register a start up script to populate the drop down lists via JavaScript.

I have since had to alter this to add values server side as well. Thus far it looks like this.

```
  protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {

        /* create controls and add some JavaScript stuff here*/

        /*Problem below*/

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            /* These seemably have to be here inspite the fact we can populate with java, issue: on postback selected values are lost. */
            for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
            {
                ddlDay.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString()));
            }

            for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
            {
                ddlMonth.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString()));
            }

            for (int i = 1901; i <= 2012; i++)
            {
                ddlYear.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString()));
            }
        }

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, Page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "<script type='text/javascript'>DateControlRender(document.getElementById('" + this.ClientID + "'));</script>", false);

        base.OnInit(e);
    }
```

Is there anyway I can get around this ? My main concern is that this will add heavily to the page size.

Thank you in advance.

Best Regards

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bottom line... you can't populate a drop down with javascript and have the ASP.NET pipeline be able to recreate the structure of the control so that there is a SelectedItem/SelectedValue.  In order for the ASP.NET pipeline to be able to capture the value selected by the user and assign it to a control, the control must be created *and populated* by the end of the Init phase.  The selection is applied after that phase, but the control and its values must be there the same way the were when they were sent to the client.

So you have a couple of options...  create the control completely server side and ditch the javascript.  Or you can use the javascript and then just get the value from the [Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form) variables.  Even though the control isn't part of the ASP.NET page you still have access to the posted values for all HTML input elements from the client in the [Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form) variables.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a custom control I guess your `ddls` are created dynamically. in this case, remember you have to create them in the "init event".  If not, the `viewstate` won't work

Comment: And each one with the same ID